# How to use R character vector element as string and variable inside function?

Tags: r, spss, expss

I am trying to apply SPSS style category labels to my dataset in R. I think my question arises as I do not know how to parse variables correctly, so is not necessarily related to just these types of data.
To begin with, doing this manually as per the `expss` library documentation works fine:

```
library(expss)

#Load in the data
data(mtcars)

#Apply Variable Labels and Value Labels (and Numeric Coding) to each Variable.
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 1,
                             "Straight engine" = 2,
                             "Other engine" = 3)
)
```

Now my problem arises if I have my "Variable Names", "Variable Labels", "Value Labels" and corresponding "Value Numeric Codes" stored in some R data type and I try to use them in the `apply_labels` function. For example, if I have these stored in character vectors like so:

```
#Load in the data
data(mtcars)

#Value Labels
value_lab<-c("V-engine","Straight engine","Other engine")
#Value's Numeric coding
value_num<-c("1","2","3")

#Variable names
var <- c("vs")
#Variable Labels
var_lab<-c("Engine")
```

Then my question is, how would I use my character vector elements inside the `apply_labels` function? e.g. how would I do something like this:

```
#Apply Variable Labels and Value Labels (and Numeric Coding) to each Variable.
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      var[1] = var_lab[1],
                      var[1] = c(value_lab[1] = value_num[1],
                                 value_lab[2] = value_num[2],
                                 value_lab[3] = value_num[3])
)
```

I have tried various combinations of `paste` and `toString` without success. My next step will be to apply this to my 500,000+ rows x 20,000 columns of data with a to-be-determined number of possible Value Labels/Numeric Codings.
Obligatory: I am new to R.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your desired result

1. Make use of named lists and vectors to store your variable and value labels
2. Doing so you can make use of `do.call` to pass the variable and value labels to `apply_labels`

To make the example more interesting I added labels for a second variable.

```r
library(expss)

# Variable Labels
var_labels <- list(vs = "Engine", am = "Transmission")
#Value Labels
val_labels <- list(
  vs = c("V-engine" = 0, "Straight engine" = 1),
  am = c("Automatic" = 0, "Manual" = 1)
)

mtcars2 <- do.call(apply_labels, c(list(data = mtcars), var_labels, val_labels))

table(mtcars2$am, mtcars2$vs)
#>            
#>             V-engine Straight engine
#>   Automatic       12               7
#>   Manual           6               7
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, thank you! That has led me to understand named lists and build a solution with `setNames`.

I ended up not using `expss`. It appeared to work within R and labelled everything as expected, but when I exported the final dataframe from R to SPSS using `haven::write_sav`, the value labels were not maintained (but the variable labels were).

Instead I used the `haven` *labelled vector class* to apply the Variable and Value labels. My final solution looks like this:

```
#Load in the data
data(mtcars)

#Variables
var <- c("vs")
#Variable Labels
var_labels<-c("Engine")

#Value Labels (for first Variable)
value_labs<-c("V-engine","Straight engine","Other engine")
#Value's Numeric coding )
value_num<-c("1","2","3")

#Make a named list to use as the value labels
value_labels <- setNames(as.integer(value_num),value_labs)

#Apply the label with haven
mtcars[,c(var[1])]<-labelled(mtcars[, c(var[1])],
                              labels=value_labels,
                              label=var_labels[1])

#Save out in spss format
haven::write_sav(mtcars, "test.sav")
```

Also, I have set it up so my data comes in one grouping of values labels at a time, but your example of expanding to the second variable helped me generalise this too, so thanks again!